# why i am been automatically login when running this command "Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/ApprovalProcess/" -UseWebLogin"

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, modern-experience, pnp-powershell, pnp

I run the following PnP command:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/ApprovalProcess/" -UseWebLogin
```

Now a dialog will open and login me automatically, and when I try to perform any action I will get access denied.

So seem I am been login using different username. How I can force the above command to ask me for the username and password and without logging me in automatically?

Comment: Which one is your default browser? Did you save the password of another account in your browser?

Comment: @GaneshSanap default browser is Edge and i am not login to any account on it...

Answer (score 0):

In fact the dialogue uses the [Internet Explorer cache and cookies](https://support.pearson.com/getsupport/s/article/Internet-Explorer-Delete-Cached-Files-and-Cookies?p=browser-usecases/browser-settings-delete-cached-files-and-cookies-ie). If you clear them, the web login should ask again for a user (you need to reopen the PowerShell instance).

Another approach is to use the parameter `SPOManagementShell` instead of UseWebLogin. This does not allow you to pick from "cached" logins though.

BR

Answer (score 0):

Update your PnP PowerShell modules to latest version and try using below command:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/ApprovalProcess/" -UseWebLogin -ForceAuthentication
```

**Reference**: [Twitter post by official PnP PowerShell account](https://twitter.com/PnpPowershell/status/1335362866069856258)